# Creating dynamic dropdown select menu filled with database data

Tags: php, javascript, drop-down-menu, autofill

I need your help to create a dynamic dropdown select menu filled with database data.

So what I need is:

- a button
- each time I press the button it creates a dropdown menu filled with database data.

I found this example it is quite similar, but I don't know how I can pass the database data to the text box or dropdown menu.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>jQuery add / remove textbox example</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'>
    <div id="TextBoxDiv1">
        <label>Textbox #1 : </label><input type='text' id='textbox1' name='textbox1'/>
    </div>
</div>
<input type='button' value='Add Button' id='addButton'/>
<input type='button' value='Remove Button' id='removeButton'/>
<input type='button' value='Get TextBox Value' id='getButtonValue'/>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 2;
    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if (counter > 10) {
            alert("Only 10 textboxes allowed");
            return false;
        }
        $('<div/>', {
            'id': 'TextBoxDiv' + counter
        }).html(
            $('<label/>').html('Textbox #' + counter + ' : ')
        )
            .append($('<input type="text">').attr({
                'id': 'textbox' + counter,
                'name': 'textbox' + counter
            }))
            .appendTo('#TextBoxesGroup')
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        if (counter == 1) {
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });
    $("#getButtonValue").click(function () {
        var msg = '';
        for (i = 1; i < counter; i++) {
            msg += "\n Textbox #" + i + " : " + $('#textbox' + i).val();
        }
        alert(msg);
    });
});
```

CSS

```
div{
    padding:8px;
}
```

[Preview](http://jsfiddle.net/BDXq2/)

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: You seem to be new to stackOverflow.
If you post any question,make sure you have researched enough about it and elaborate your problems with more expressive question.Post your code in the questions.Learn how to use fiddle.
The people answering your question are smart enough to use fiddle.You dont need to mention it.Use meta stackoverflow to learn how to ask question.
What have you done so far!!!
This is a vague question

Comment: a) Do more research, b) come up with a real, very specific, question, c) don't post links with code.

Comment: Sorry but i don't know what yuo mean i'm asking if you can help me to fill this textbox or a dropdown with the database data...I searched too much and i have not found nothing that can help me. That is the reason I'm on this forum ... of course  Thanks a lot

Comment: p.s. for the first user: the question is if you can help me ... if not do not answer me it is only a controversy